# Java Regex, difference between " " and "\\s\\s"

Tags: java

To my understanding, the character class \s represents all the possible whitespace characters.

Considering the following string: `"  AB  CA"`.

Is there any difference or sneaky gotcha's about using regex `"(  [a-zA-Z]{2}){2}"`

I was inclined to begin with `"(\\s\\s[a-zA-Z]{2}){2}"` as my pattern.

Considering my string, `"  AB  CA"`, is there any difference at all in which regex pattern I choose here: two spaces `"  "`, or the whitespace character class `"\\s\\s"`

?

Comment: "\s" also matches tabs, and,depending on mode, newlines.

Comment: Yes, I guess using whitespace might match more than just my exact example string. I somehow thought the character class might be more system independent or something, but  it's actually going to widen my net. I suppose the two space characters is the most narrow search for a match in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that it is two space characters, you should use `"  "` instead of `\\s\\s` because `\\s` means any whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

Comment: Yes, thanks. Somebody replaced ", AB, CA" in a CSV as two spaces instead of the comma, so it wouldn't mess up the comma delimited file. The two spaces ... in that exact circumstance, is what I'm replacing back to a comma and a space and then the two letters. I'll use the two spaces in my pattern to be more exact, thanks.

Comment: Oops, haven't asked enough questions to know the ropes yet. Thanks for reminding me. :)